# android emulator-x86 network connection disabled

Tags: android, x86, emulation, intel

I found an ugly problem on android emulator-x86.

platform: windows/ubuntu
android sdk version: 18,19,21
systemImage: atom
emulator: emulator64-x86 / emulator-x86

if I use the browser to download some big data files, the emulator network will be disabled soon, and It will not to be resumed until I restart the emulator

Is there anybody know how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer, but why don't you try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)? I've used the android emulator in the past and have some distasteful memories....

Comment: the kernel is build by myself, I am not sure if I can use Genymotion